# How can I get the number of characters from an input string?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to count the number of characters in a string that is provided by the user. I know I can use `string::length()` and `string::size()` but when a space is encountered, the count is stopped. For example, say the user inputs "Bob Builder", the count should be 10 but what my code would display would be 3. Also I am trying to do this without using a character array. Any suggestions? An explanation would also greatly help.

```
    int main()
    {
       string Name;
       cin>>Name;
       cout << name(Name);
       return 0;
    }

    int name(string a)
    {
        int numChar;
        /*for (int i=0; a[i] != '\0';i++)
        {
             if (!isspace(a[i]))
             numChar++;
        }*/
        numChar=a.length();
        return numChar;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead of `cin` to get all line up to newline. `cin` reads input up to whitespace.

```
std::getline (std::cin,Name);
```

If you use `using namespace std;`

```
getline (cin,Name);
```

If you want to count the input string excluding spaces, the code snippet helps you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "Hello there, world!";
    std::cout << std::count( s.begin(), s.end(), ' ' ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How yu know when input is over?
If you want to read until end of line then this is a possible solution:

```
std::string line ;
std::cin.getline(line) ;
line.length() ;
```

Comment: This code won't compile. `std::cin.getline()` only accepts a `char*`. You meant `std::getline(std::cin, line)` like the other (correct) answer.

Comment: Have you thought about fixing the obviously incorrect code in your answer? Perhaps as a courtesy to the people that voted without bothering to read it.